# installation of java 8 on (debian 9) python:3 docker image using terminal commands

Tags: java, python-3.x, docker

I have tried a lot of things on the internet but am unable to successfully install java 8 on my python:3.7-slim-stretch base image. I specifically need java 8 on debian 9 due to incompatibility issues(apparently of pyspark hadoop and java)in the project I am working on which it throwing this error.:
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jdk
```

and

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java \
&& apt update \
&& apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps

```
FROM  python:3.7-slim-stretch
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: yes i had tried this also. It apparently installs the java but when i check java -- version , it does not show any version. So i am not sure java is properly getting installed or not. Also it did not remove the compatibility issue i was facing so i thought it did not work properly maybe. Thanks though!

Comment: when I tried java -version, I got 

openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-1~deb9u1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode) as output. Can you please explain what other things are you installing along with this?